# Mongo DBCursor behave differently in Tomcat and plain Java process

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

In my tomcat app, I query records in mongodb using DBCursor, when there are too many records, the cursor will stuck at .next(), then, SocketTimeoutException will be thrown.

While, if I do it in a standalone java process(start by java -jar XXX.jar MyClass), this won't happen.

Any suggestion why this happened?
Thanks

PS.I doubt if it is caused by the memory limit of each tomcat thread or something.

Answer (score 0):

**Reduce your keepAliveTime to 5mins (300 seconds)** for mongodb. Generally, kkepAliveTime is set to 2 hours (7200 seconds).

For more [info](https://jira.mongodb.org/i#browse/JAVA-721).